# Normal Thread,ProgressDialog,Screen Orientation Change in Android Application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am a cub in android development but i am facing difficult problem now.Please try to help me.
In my app i have used onRetainNonConfigChange() to hold the object and used after activity created.
       I know about handling this problem with AsynchTask thread with ProgressDialog but The same problem i can't able to handle with normal Thread and Hanlder.
       I tried all the ways like make the Thread class as static and pass the parameters through on Handler class update the UI but...no use....
"How to handle screen orientation change with Normal Thread handler in android"

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `AsyncTask` still. Because it says in the SDK:

**if your retained state is an AsyncTask you are guaranteed that its call back functions (like onPostExecute(Result)) will not be called from the call here until you execute the next instance's onCreate(Bundle).**

Comment: I have completed Where the AyncTask Method used for This Orienatation changes..It works perfectly but i am stuck with where the Thread and Handler using in this scenario i can't able to attach or detach activity with the thread...And it's not update my UI after thread completion.